# Zend_Form with Ajax/json

Tags: zend-framework, jquery, zend-form

I'm a bit lost using Zend_Form with Ajax. I have a form in a class extending Zend_Form called from my controller, that way :

*GoodAddGroup.php*

```
class Default_Form_GoodAddGroup extends Zend_Form {
    (...)

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAction("process-add-group");
        $this->setName("addgroupgood");

        // Load Elements class
        require "Form/Elements.php";
        $magElements = new Elements();

        // Category
        $categoryElement = $magElements->getCategorySelectField();
        $categoryElement->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators);

        // Barcode
        $barcodeElement = $magElements->getGoodBarcodeTextField();
        $barcodeElement->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators);

        (...)

        // Add elements to the form
        $this->addElements(array(
            $categoryElement,
            //$codeElement,
            $barcodeElement,
            $serialElement,
            $warehouseElement,
            $submitButtonElement
        ));
        $this->setDecorators($this->formDecorators);
    }
}
```

In *GoodsController.php*

```
private function getAddGroupForm()
{
    return new Default_Form_GoodAddGroup();
}

public function addGroupAction()
{
    // Initialize the form for the view.
    $this->view->form = $this->getAddGroupForm();
}

public function processAddGroupAction()
{

        $form = $this->getAddGroupForm();
    (...)

    if ($_POST)
    {
        if ($form->isValid($_POST))
        {
            // Do things
        } else {
            $this->view->form = $form;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the form has a category select field, when selecting a category, a second "code" selector is added filled with the items related to this category. When the page with the form is displayed (http://myapp/goods/add-group), everything works fine, the ajax call does its job, the second select field is added and well fed, but as you can see, the form processing is done with the processAddGroupAction(), this method get the instance of the form to get its values and to re-display it in case of problem. But that way, my "new" select field doesn't exist anymore, so i can never validate the form.

It's my first attempt using ajax/json with Zend, i think i need help at this poind.

Thank you.

**EDIT :** added the view code as requested

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#cats").change(function(){
            getSelectBox(this);
        });

        $("#code").parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
        getSelectBox($("#cats"));
    });

    function getSelectBox(element)
    {
        if($(element).val() != '')
        {
            $("#code").parent().parent().css('display', 'block');
            if ($('#code').length <= 0) {
                $("#cats").after('<select name="code" id="code" style="margin-left:10px"></select>');
            }
            $.getJSON("/goods/json-get-codes-from-category", {id: $(element).val(), ajax: "true"}, function(j){
                console.log(j);
                var options = "";
                jQuery.each(j, function(i, val) {
                    options += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + val + '</option>';
                });
                $("#code").html(options);
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution! I post it in case it can be useful for other people.
I knew what was the problem, but unable to know how to achieve it.

At form processing time, the new select element does not exist for the action as it has been added in the view with javascript. To fix this, we need to inform the action about the new field, to do so, we first need to override the method “isValid” of Zend_Form in the form class :

```
public function isValid($values)
{
    $values = $this->_modifyElements($values);   
    return parent::isValid($values);
}
```

Then create a method "_modifyElements" that will modify the form by adding the new element :

```
protected function _modifyElements($values)
    {
        // Search for codes
        $dbu = new DbUtils();
        $codes = $dbu->getCodesFromCategory($values['cats']);

        // Remove the current code element
        $this->removeElement('code');

        // Create a new element
        $codeElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('code', array());
        $codeElement->setLabel(_('Code :'));
        $codeElement->setRequired(true);
        $codeElement->addMultiOptions($codes);
        $codeElement->setValue($values['code']);
        $codeElement->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators);
        $this->addElement($codeElement);

        return $values;
    }
```

We have to override the method "populate" too :

```
public function populate(array $values)
{
    $values = $this->_modifyElements($values);   
    return parent::populate($values);
}
```

And voilà. It works for me ;>
All the credits about this go to Mohamed : http://jamandcheese-on-phptoast.com/2009/12/13/on-fly-elements-in-zend_form/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the select element 'code' in the form, but don't display it in the view (it will be created from the js). So when the form is posted the 'code' will also be validated since it is in the $_POST.
After post you have to display the select box without  `$("#cats").change({..})`. You can accomplish it by spiting the js code into functions

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#cats").change(function(){
            getSelectBox(this);
        });

        getSelectBox($("#cats"));
    });

    function getSelectBox(element)
    {
        if($(element).val() != '')
        {
            if ($('#code').length <= 0) {
                $("#cats").after('<select name="code" id="code" style="margin-left:10px"></select>');
            }
            $.getJSON("/goods/json-get-codes-from-category", {id: $(element).val(), ajax: "true"}, function(j){
                console.log(j);
                var options = "";
                jQuery.each(j, function(i, val) {
                    options += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + val + '</option>';
                });
                $("#code").html(options);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem remains the same. I omitted it in the copy/paste (i edited it by now though), but in the processAddAction, i get the form in order to validate it and process it, so i guess that getting the instance of Default_Form_GoodAddGroup, there is no 'code' select element yet as it's added with javascript in the view. Then i'm confused how to process the form now..

Comment: you have to add the element 'code' in the form too. From the code you have pasted i think `$codeElement` is the the select-box. Uncomment it in the Form Class, but dont print it in the view

Comment: Thank you Nandakumar, that is something i tried, but when processing the form, the select element now exists but remains empty anyway (with no option filled).
(view added in the original post btw)

Comment: 'but remains empty anyway', is that happening before or after posting the form.   Also when you are adding options to a Zend Form Select from ajax, you have to set [setRegisterInArrayValidator(false)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.select) . Otherwise the zend form `isValid` will return `false`